# Regexp string replacement

Tags: javascript, regex

This simple code is supposed to replace a substring based on a regExp, but strange enough it seems to skip every other match. I'm struggling to figure it out what's the problem. The `while` is part of a [3rd party code](https://github.com/iminif/html-replace-webpack-plugin/blob/master/index.js#L22), I would prefer not changing it.

```js
var text = `
<!-- build:js[vendor0.js] -->
xx
<!-- /build -->
<!-- build:js[vendor1.js] -->
xx
<!-- /build -->
<!-- build:js[vendor2.js] -->
xx
<!-- /build -->
<!-- build:js[vendor3.js] -->
xx
<!-- /build -->
<!-- build:js[vendor4.js] -->
xx
<!-- /build -->
`
var regex = /<!-- build:([\s\S]*?)\[([\s\S]*?)] -->[\s\S]*?<!-- \/build -->/gm
var replacementFn = function(match, type, path) { return `REPLACED: ${type} - ${path}` }

// 3rd party code
while ((matches = regex.exec(text)) != null) {
          var replacement = replacementFn.apply(null, matches)
          text = text.replace(matches[0], replacement)
}
// end 3rd party code
console.log(text)
```

**SOLUTION**:
From here [JS regex skips every other match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060685/js-regex-skips-every-other-match)
It seems just dropping the global flag solved.

Answer (score 3):

RegExp's are stateful, meaning that the call to `exec` "remembers" the last place the match was, and starts from there on the next invocation.  You might rather use `String.prototype.match` to avoid the stateful behavior of the call to RegExp.exec.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: I know that, actually that's why we are able to iterate over `regex.exec(text)`, but why that specific regExp has that strange behaviour? One matched and one skipped?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change the while loop, it might be helpful. Figure I'd provide an answer. Using `replace`.

```js
var text = `
<!-- build:js[vendor0.js] -->
xx
<!-- /build -->
<!-- build:js[vendor1.js] -->
xx
<!-- /build -->
<!-- build:js[vendor2.js] -->
xx
<!-- /build -->
<!-- build:js[vendor3.js] -->
xx
<!-- /build -->
<!-- build:js[vendor4.js] -->
xx
<!-- /build -->
`;

var regex = /<!-- build:([\s\S]*?)\[([\s\S]*?)] -->[\s\S]*?<!-- \/build -->/gm

var replacement = function(match, type, path) {
  return `REPLACED: ${type} - ${path}`;
}

console.log(text.replace(regex, replacement));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//var regex = /<!-- build:([\s\S]*?)\[([\s\S]*?)] -->[\s\S]*?<!-- \/build -->/gm
var replacementFn = function(match, type, path) { return `REPLACED: ${type} - ${path}` }

// 3rd party code
while ((matches = /<!-- build:([\s\S]*?)\[([\s\S]*?)] -->[\s\S]*?<!-- \/build -->/gm.exec(text)) != null) {
          var replacement = replacementFn.apply(null, matches)
          text = text.replace(matches[0], replacement)
}
// end 3rd party code
console.log(text)
```

You must create a new Regex instance for each while loop
or

```js
var regex = function(){
 return /<!-- build:([\s\S]*?)\[([\s\S]*?)] -->[\s\S]*?<!-- \/build -->/gm
}
var replacementFn = function(match, type, path) { return `REPLACED: ${type} - ${path}` }

// 3rd party code
while ((matches = regex().exec(text)) != null) {
          var replacement = replacementFn.apply(null, matches)
          text = text.replace(matches[0], replacement)
}
// end 3rd party code
console.log(text)
```